# ansible - deploy a 3 tiers application on 3 different machines

Tags: ansible

I have a basic application with:
- db
- api (connected to the  db)
- front end (connected to the http api)

I'd like the 3 services to run on 3 differents machines. I'm using ansible to perform this but I'm not quite sure about how to define the environment variables so each layer knows how to connect to the underlying one.

- api needs DB_HOST and DB_PORT to connect to the DB. It also needs to be provided a PORT for its own usage.
- front end needs API_HOST and API_PORT to connect to the API.  It also needs to be provided a PORT for its own usage.

inventory.ini

```
[www]
192.168.1.120

[api]
192.168.1.120

[db]
192.168.1.120

[myproj:children]
www
api
db

[myproj:vars]
db_host=192.168.1.120      // needed by the api
db_port=27017              // needed by the api
api_host=192.168.1.120     // needed by the front-end
api_port=8000              // needed by the api + front-end
www_port=8001              // needed by the front-end
```

Note: for my test I use only one vagrant VM but the 3 machines will be distinct in production.

playbooks.yml

```
---  
- hosts: db
  sudo: True
  roles:
    - common
    - db
- hosts: api
  sudo: True
  roles:
    - common
    - api
- hosts: www
  sudo: True
  roles:
    - common
    - www
```

Example with the api roles: (roles/api/tasks/main.yml)

```
---
- name: clone api
  git: repo=git@github.com:...

- name: install api packages
  ...

- name: start api 
  sudo: False
  shell: npm start
  args:
    chdir: /var/app
  environment:
    PORT: ???
    DB_HOST: ???
    DB_PORT: ???
```

I'd like to have the DB_HOST / DB_PORT / PORT setup from the hostvars but I do not manage to retrieve the variable I've set in the inventory.
Is that a good way to handle this ?
Should I declare those variables somewhere else ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do some refactoring. Having variables in your inventory file is generally against Ansible best prices. This page describes optimal layout of your playbooks http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#content-organization

Furthermore, in your inventory file `www`, `api` and `db` are group names.
What you can do is this:

```
[www]
web01 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.120

[api]
api01 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.120

[db]
db01 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.120
```

This way you can refer to your servers using a bit friendlier names, making your playbooks more readable.

As for getting, for example database IP, you can use host facts to extract it as such:

```
{{ hostvars[db01]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
```

or, if you want to do it via an index into a group:

```
{{ hostvars[groups['db'][0]]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
```

You should take a look at other facts that Ansible collects and see if anything there suits your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what the question is, but is this what you're looking for:

```
- name: start api 
  sudo: False
  shell: npm start
  args:
    chdir: /var/app
  environment:
    PORT: "{{P_PORT}}"
    DB_HOST: "{{P_DB_HOST}}"
    DB_PORT: "{{P_DB_PORT}}"
```

Include the role like:

```
roles:
  - { role:api, PORT="{{P_PORT}}", DB_HOST="{{P_DB_HOST}}", DB_PORT="{{P_DB_PORT}}" }
```